# SQL - how to get out chained data?

Tags: sql, orm

I have 4 tables which were auto generated for me:

- User
- Challenge
- Exercise
- Challenge_Exercise

One User may have many Challenges, and one Challenge will have many Exercises.

What I noticed is that the Challenge table has a reference to it's parent User (called user_id) but Exercise do not have a reference in it's table to Challenge; their relation is stored in Challenge_Exercise as Challenge_id and exercise_id.

My question is, how would I take out every Exercise that is linked to a specific user? For instance User with id = 1?

Comment: @Laurence, I had already done that but I did not understand the examples. There were no examples which were similar to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   excerise,
       challenge_excerise,
       challenge
WHERE  challenge.user_id = 1
       AND challenge_excerise.challenge_id = challenge.id
       AND challenge_excerise.exercise_id = excercise.id
```

What I'm doing here is a `join`, you could also explicitly do it with `inner joins` (google it if you wanna know more).

This table is needed because you have a `many to many` relationship, which means each challenge can have multiple exercises, but also each exercise can have multiple challenges. It's a standard to make an extra table then, so you don't have redundant data, this table is often called `junction table`.

If you want background just google it, there are tons of data to this topic.

Comment: Please look into ANSI-style joins, they're much easier to read! Worth a read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I know these joins, these I meant with "explicitly do it". Personally  I don't find them much easier to read.